# Deformation retraction from $SO(a,b)$ to $SO(a) \times SO(b)$

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

Let $a,b \geq 1$. I want to find deformation restract from $SO(a,b)$ to $SO(a) \times SO(b)$.
Obviously, $SO(a)\times SO(b)$ can be included as $SO(a,b)$ via simple block form.
But how to construct the deformation retract of them?

Comment: ${\rm SO}(a,b)$ is not connected.  Did you mean ${\rm SO}^+(a,b)$?

Comment: The usual tool is that if $G$ is a connected semisimple group with maximal compact subgroup $K$ then $G$ deformation-retracts to $K$. Now, can you find a maximal compact subgroup in your group?

Comment: To expand on Moishe's comment: this result follows from the Cartan Decomposition of $G$: to quote https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan_decomposition: "The mapping $K\times \mathfrak{p} \rightarrow G$ given by $(k,X) \mapsto k \cdot \mathrm{exp} (X)$ is a diffeomorphism."

Comment: So you can just SLRRRRRRRRRRRRP retract the $\exp(\mathfrak{p})$ part (which is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$ for some $m$) away and end up with $K$.

Comment: I would guess that someone asking this question probably doesn't know enough Lie theory to use the above and wants a more elementary solution.